# Uploading Rails to a website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, postgresql, file-upload

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have developed my own web application, and it is running well on my local rails server. But the question is - How can I upload it to a website?

Right now I have a website on freehostingnoads.net, in near future I want to upload it to amazon EC2.

Can I upload it through FTP (FileZilla), like HTML file. If not, then how can I do that? Obviously uploading it with the database (I use PostgreSQL).

On the Internet I can find tutorials only for uploading it to different local servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) script for deployment. This is recommended way at present for deployment Rails applications to remote servers.

But this is not a one way to do it. So, you can use other approaches i.e. build and deploy Docker containers or copy sources over FTP manually (this is not recommended but possible way).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can not deploy or run your rails app in freehostingnoads.net, they neither have ruby nor postgres. They do not provide enough SSH privilege or their in-built tool for deployment. You will have to run another server along with Apache or Nginx which is not possible in your provided host.

I would suggest you to checkout [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), which is the best (to my knowledge) for hosting rails app for free. They have Postgres db in their free hosting package.

Here is the simple [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) on how-to deploy your first app.

Answer (score 0):

for my rails deployments i have an ec2 instance which i rsync the project or git clone the project into then have a server manager like `foreman` to take care of the server, because rails depends on ruby being installed on the server's OS. shared hosting will not cut it